# update-database [Specific Migration] applies all migrations

Tags: entity-framework-core

I am using update-database IdentityMigration just to apply this migration only .
but this apply all migrations

I Tried to use
`Update-database MyMigrationName` but this command apply all migrations .
I am using entity framework code .
and i am trying to apply only identity tables to my database

Comment: Does the database have a table called `__EFMigrationsHistory`? If so, is/was that table adequatley filled with the names of all migrations that supposedly had already been executed?

Comment: but i need to apply only specific migration

Comment: That is just not how migrations work. They always go from a "before" state to an "after" state, with just the right commands to do so. If your "before" state is old then it will start at that old state and do all commands from there.